# SKAction.waitForDuration not working in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been pulling my hair out over this seemingly simple feature I'm trying to build in to a game I am working on in SpriteKit and Swift. I have searched and can't figure why this isn't working.

What I want to do:
When the player comes in contact with an enemy or an obstacle, I want to load and play through an explosion animation createExplosion() (The animation completes in 0.5 seconds) and then progress to the gameOverAction(). The problem is that only the first frame of the animation is shown and then it progresses to the gameOverAction().
I tried to make an SKAction.sequence but Xcode did not like me calling functions inside the sequence, so I found SKAction.waitForDuration. Problem is, it is having no effect on the execution of the code.
How should this be done properly?

```
func collisionWithPlayer(playerObject: SKSpriteNode) {
    runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("spaceExplosion.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
    createExplosion(playerObject)
    playerObject.removeFromParent()
    runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(0.5)))
    gameOverAction()
    }
```

And here is the code for the gameOverAction():

```
func gameOverAction()   {

    backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()

    globalHighScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("GameHighScore") as? Int 

    localHighScore = self.monstersDestroyed

    if globalHighScore == nil {
        globalHighScore = localHighScore
    }

    globalHighScore = self.recordHighScore(localHighScore, highScore: globalHighScore!)
    println(globalHighScore!)

    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0)
    let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
}

func createExplosion(object: SKSpriteNode) -> SKSpriteNode {

    var explosionArray = Array<SKTexture>()
    var explosionSprite = SKSpriteNode()

    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite01.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite02.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite03.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite04.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite05.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite06.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite07.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite08.png"))
    explosionArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "explosionSprite09.png"))

    let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(explosionArray, timePerFrame: 0.05)
    explosionSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:explosionArray[0])
    explosionSprite.position = CGPoint(x: object.position.x + 10.0, y: object.position.y)
    addChild(explosionSprite)
    explosionSprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([animateAction, SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
    return(explosionSprite)
}
```

Comment: You need to run the gameOverAction as a sequence after waitForDuration

Comment: Could you post the method for gameOverAction as well?

Comment: I added the code. Whenever I tried to include a method call in a SKAction.sequence I could not make Xcode happy. I understand that a method is not an SKAction, so I tried .runBlock with an equal lack of success.

Answer (score 2):

The `waitForDuration` SKAction can be used to introduce a delay into an action sequence, but it doesn't block the thread calling `runAction` - so your `waitForDuration` action will be set to run on your node, but then `gameOverAction()` will be called immediately.

You can use the completion block of `runAction:completion` to perform `gameOverAction()` after the actions are complete -

```
func collisionWithPlayer(playerObject: SKSpriteNode) {
    var actions = Array<SKAction>();
     actions.append(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("spaceExplosion.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
     actions.append(SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(0.5)))
     actions.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
     createExplosion(playerObject)
     let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions);
     playerObject.runAction(sequence,completion: { () -> Void in
         self.gameOverAction()
     })
}
```

Depending on what `createExplosion` does it may be possible to incorporate it into the sequence too and remove the need for the `waitForDuration`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paulw11, I'm halfway there... When I implement your code suggestions, only the first action in the actions Array is called, the createExplosion is called and completes, but gameOverAction() is never called. Why is it not going through the rest of the actions[] values?

Comment: Also, Xcode is requiring me to add self.gameOverAction() in the completion statement, this doesn't make sense to me since gameOverAction does not belong to collisionWithPlayer? I admit, my understanding of this is not at all complete.

Comment: Self refers to the current object instance, not the current function - game over action is a method on the current object, so you need to use self to indicate that.

Comment: included the createExplosion method

Comment: I am not sure why your completion handler isn't being called.  Set a breakpoint to make sure.  The only reason I can think of is that you are removing the actions somewhere else.

Comment: Does this ("The waitForDuration SKAction can be used to introduce a delay into an action sequence, but it doesn't block the thread calling runAction - so your waitForDuration action will be set to run on your node, but then gameOverAction() will be called immediately.") mean that waitForDuration only affects the subsequent actions that are contents of an ActionSequence containing the waitForDuration action?

Comment: Exactly. Think of the action sequence as a "script" for that node. You are putting a delay into the script, but not a delay into your whole app